# How do I zcat two files inline to perform diff?

Tags: linux, bash, zcat

How can I zcat 2 .gz files inline to perform a diff in unix? Have tried eval but syntax not right.

```
zcat file1.gz zcat file2.gz
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/587442/3776858

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
diff <(zcat file1.gz) <(zcat file2.gz)
```